# GORM - Model Relationships Between Like Entities

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm

For my project I'm using Grails, but this is kind of a general ORM question.

I'm new to ORMs and ER diagrams, and trying to figure out how to best describe/implement the following:

I have 2 Entities: User, Connection

A Connection consists of 2 Users (and other primitive attributes).  A user can be found in more than one Connection.  How would you describe the relationship between User and Connection?  I don't know what you would call it, 2 to many?  How would you draw it in an ER diagram.

In GORM, should it be a bi-directional relationship?

*Edit*

As an added requirement, assume the users have specific roles in the relationship.  Like student and teacher. So Connection would have student and teacher properties of type User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want can be described as a [many-to-many relationship](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany), with some sort of constraint applied on Connection `users` collection. As for uni/bi-directional, I believe you can accomplish either depending on your use case - although uni-directional is probably harder to map/configure.

I haven't tested this, but a **bi-directional** many-to-many should look like this

```
class Connection {
  ...
  Set users = [] //ensure users exists, constraints won't work on null 
  static belongsTo = [User] 
  static hasMany = [users: User]

  static constraints = {
    users maxSize: 2
  }
}

class User {
  ...
  static hasMany = [connections: Connection]
}
```

<strike>I don't have a uni-directional example off the top of my head, but I believe you may need to use an additional mapping class.</strike>

Again, I haven't tested this, but here's an example of **uni-directional** many-to-many with a mapping class

```
class Connection {
  ...
  Set users = []
  static hasMany = [users: ConnectionUser]
  static constraints = {
    users maxSize: 2
  }
}

class User {
  ...
}

class ConnectionUser {
  User user
  Connection connection
  //or for cascading effects
  //static belongsTo = [connection: Connection]
  ...
  ... //lots of additional code to manage adding,
  ... //removing, updating Connection-to-User relationships
}
```

Connection knows about Users, but Users do not know about Connections they belong to. If you go the mapping class route, you'll need to manage the Connection to User relationships manually. Take a look at [Spring Security Core PersonAuthority](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.3%20PersonAuthority%20Class) class for an example of mapping class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.  I guess that makes sense.  I'm going to see if anyone else has any thoughts before accepting the answer.

Comment: What about if the two users have specific roles in the connection and need to be two different fields.  Like student and teacher.  But still a student can have many teachers.  A teacher can have many students.

Comment: I guess I could just make it an ordered collection instead of 2 fields?  But I would like to say connection.student or connection.teacher.

Comment: Or maybe just using a Map for the hasMany would work.  And just index using ["student"] or ["teacher"]

Comment: i think you can make Users two separate fields as well, you'll just need to configure a [mappedBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html), otherwise Grails will be confused

Comment: Map will work too. Map users = [:] <br/> static mapping = { users mapKey: 'somekey' }

Comment: you are right, the airport and flight example in the manual is the same thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not GORM, your problem deals with Entities. Before you code Domain classes, you have to image distinctly what info you would like to keep and operate. According your question and comments you prefer to use any RDBS. So let's to try to image easy simple tables (don't care about any ORM, Grails, bi\uni-directions) and try to fill this tables mock details.

**Users**

- nickName (String)
- otherUsersFields

**Connection**

- teacher (Users)
- student (Users)
- otherConnectionFields

well, now we know all Users and all Connections. For given connection we can say who is teacher - connection.teacher and student - connection.student.

***Note:** any Connection has only two users.*

pay attention to Users. Any User can be Student and Teacher. If User can be only Student or Teacher you will have to add additional field(s), for example

**Users**

- nickName (String)
- isTeacher (boolean)
- otherUsersFields

now we have a list of user and know who is st. or tech.
How can I get all connections for given user?
GORM offers: Connection.findAllByStudent( givenUser), Connection.findAllByTeacher( givenUser)

Do this tables show your info completely?